# How to merge array in php and encode by json?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two tables. From visit_reports table i get just one row for this id but in  reviewed_reports I get 2 rows.

```
$sql = "select * from visit_reports WHERE visit_planner_id='$id'";
$query = sqlsrv_query( $link, $sql);

$sql2 = "select yes_no_not_app,comments from reviewed_reports WHERE visit_planner_id='$id'";
while($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $val = $data;
        }

    while($data2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query2,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $val2[] = $data2;
        }

    $val4 = array_merge($val, $val2);
    echo json_encode($val4);
```

from this i get

```
{"id":1,"visit_planner_id":230338,"company_name":"ShafiConsultancy","short_title":"SC","report_name":"test report","trial_no":1,"site_id":1,"date_of_report":"11\/05\/2015","date_of_visit" :"11\/05\/2015","date_of_previous_visit":"11\/05\/2015","investigator_name":"rana","investigato   r_address":"shopnil","patient_enrolled":"no","enrolled_discont":"no","patient_entered":"no","entered   _discont":"yes","completed":"yes","cml_name":"test cml","cra_name":"test cra","phone":123456,"fax":123456,"email":"rana@gmail.com"
,"site_staff_present_name":"test staff","site_staff_trial_function":"test    staff     trial","bi_staff_present_name" :"test staff","bi_staff_trial_function":"trest staff trial","0":    {"yes_no_not_app":"Yes","comments":"test comment 1"},"1":{"yes_no_not_app":"no","comments":"test comment 2"}}'
```

I want like this

```
{"id":1,"visit_planner_id":230338,"company_name":"ShafiConsultancy","short_title":"SC","report_name":"test report","trial_no":1,"site_id":1,"date_of_report":"11\/05\/2015","date_of_visit" :"11\/05\/2015","date_of_previous_visit":"11\/05\/2015","investigator_name":"rana","investigato   r_address":"shopnil","patient_enrolled":"no","enrolled_discont":"no","patient_entered":"no","entered   _discont":"yes","completed":"yes","cml_name":"test cml","cra_name":"test cra","phone":123456,"fax":123456,"email":"rana@gmail.com"
,"site_staff_present_name":"test staff","site_staff_trial_function":"test    staff     trial","bi_staff_present_name" :"test staff","bi_staff_trial_function":"trest staff trial",    "yes_no_not_app":"Yes","comments":"test comment 1","yes_no_not_app":"no","comments":"test comment 2"}'
```

I want to all in one array. How  could I do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415177/place-multiple-result-in-a-single-array

Comment: Are we supposed to spot the difference in those two enormous JSON blobs? Please explain better what you want.

Comment: The output you want is not possible. The keys 'yes_no_not_app' and 'comments' would overwrite each other because, as @Niranjan has pointed out, you cannot have duplicate keys in an array. It is valid currently because they are wrapped in their own objects.

Answer (score 0):

**you cannot have same index names in one array**

Check this rows.

```
while($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $val = $data;
    }

while($data2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query2,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $val2[] = $data2;   <--- array index is added, remove this.
    }
```

Comment: But there are two values stored `$val[]`. So removing index is unnecessary

Comment: you cannot have same index names.

Comment: I remove [] this but i get  just one value which is latest.    As like      {..........
"site_staff_trial_function":"test staff trial","bi_staff_present_name"
:"test staff","bi_staff_trial_function":"trest staff trial","yes_no_not_app":"no","comments":"test comment
 2"}.

Comment: @MohibulHasanRana this is because, you cannot have duplicate key in an array.

Comment: Now what should I do ? I want to get all the values of this Id and send them to in a modal form to edit this modal form if needed by javascript.